# After update to 14.04, ncurses seems to have bugs (cursor still visible in petris)

Tags: 14.04, command-line, cursor, ncurses

I just upgraded to 14.04, and wanted to kill time by playing some petris. Then I noticed this:

[image]

The problem also exists in other terminals. Is there some option I can set to get the terminal to not show the cursor when it isn't supposed to? (I tried switching cursor style to I-beam, but then it constantly blinks, which is even more distracting.)

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicate, he did not want to stop it flashing but dissable it all together

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the`setterm` commands

For your perticuler problem run

```
sudo setterm -cursor off
```

This will turn off the cursor

```
sudo setterm -cursor on
```

This will bring it back

PLease see this manual for more setterm attributes

For the strange problem of the cursor re appearing when you start the game, try starting it like this.

```
sudo petris && setterm -cursor off
```

Adjust the word petris to whatever command starts the game if nessassery, this will start the game then turn off the cursor one it started.

Also these commands work in a `x-term`, try with that its pre installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: This suggestion doesn't address my problem. The issue isn't that the cursor is blinking, it's that the cursor is visible at all.

Comment: I missunderstood sorry, updated the answer

Comment: whoa! this turns off the cursor, and then something both unexpected and disturbing happens. When I play petris, the cursor _comes back all on its own_, even after I close out of petris.

Comment: Modified the answer for you

Comment: The problem stubbornly persists... perhaps it's a bug in petris?? Maybe when it fires up ncurses it sends some incorrect signal to the terminal turning the cursor back on?

Comment: Same if you use the xterm

Comment: Also my reserch suggests (but does not quite confirm) this is a badly coded, flash game ported to Linux terminals, so could just be a crap port, here you will find a more highly rated Tetris clone for Terminal, Vetris http://www.victornils.net/tetris/ and here is another I think looks nicer http://helpforlinux.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/play-tetris-in-ubuntu-terminal.html